# CUDA Segmentation fault in threads with no CUDA code

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, cuda

I have this code:

```
__global__ void testCuda() {}

void wrapperLock()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexCudaExecution);

    // changing this value to 20000 does NOT trigger "Segmentation fault"
    usleep(5000);
    runCuda();
}

void runCuda()
{
    testCuda<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

When these functions are executed from around 20 threads then I get `Segmentation fault`. As written in the comment, changing the value in `usleep()` to 20000 works fine.

Is there an issue with CUDA and threads?
It looks to me like CUDA needs a bit of time to recover when an execution finished even when there was nothing to do.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you're launching multiple host threads and each one is trying to launch a CUDA kernel? Just one CUDA context?

Comment: Yes, but they are NOT executed simultaneously because of std::lock_guard which blocks the launch of another CUDA kernel as long the previous did not finish! This is in my eyes so strange.

Comment: are you binding the cuda context with each thread before calling the launch?

Comment: No, I am doing what you see. Can you please provide me more information regarding the "binding"? What should I do?

Comment: You could try putting a `cudaSetDevice(0);` call before the kernel call in `runCuda`. I would suggest providing a complete example.

Comment: This is the complete example.

Comment: No, I mean [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That would include a fully compilable sample, that requires nothing to be added to compile and run.

Comment: I built [a complete code](http://pastebin.com/hRQiLmHc) around what you have shown here.  No problem with 25 threads.  If I comment out the `usleep` call, it still works.  If I comment out the `cudaSetDevice` call, it still works.  I think you should show a complete code.

Comment: @Robert: Which nvcc/CUDA version are you using? 6.0 does not accept -std parameter. I have to split the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

*According to http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#um-gpu-exclusive the problem was a concurrent access to the Unified Memory I am using. I had to wrap the CUDA kernel calls **and access to the Unified Memory** with a `std::lock_guard` and now the program runs for 4 days under heavy thread load without any problems.*

I have to call in each thread - as suggested by Marco & Robert - `cudaSetDevice` otherwise it crashes again.

Comment: I don't really understand why somebody thinks the answer is not useful! I admit I made a mistake and the answer should help other to check first their code before posting in SO. I have at least cojones to admin an own mistake/bug.

Answer (score 3):

Using a single CUDA context, multiple host threads should either delegate their CUDA work to a context-owner thread (similar to a worker thread) or bind the context with [cuCtxSetCurrent](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__CTX_gbe562ee6258b4fcc272ca6478ca2a2f7.html) (driver API) or [cudaSetDevice](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DRIVER.html) in order to not overwrite the context resources.

Comment: I am not capable to sort it out. It would be very nice of you if you could provide me a sample code what to do in the function runCuda(), how to initialize it in main()...

Comment: @AlBundy This might help you: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-always-set-current-device-avoid-multithreading-bugs/

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. I am locking the threads with std::lock_guard<std::mutex> - this means there is always EXACTLY ONE thread using the GPU. And why does it work when I use the usleep(20000) function? What I understand regarding the Context is, I have to use it when multiple threads are using the GPU concurrently.

Comment: You should do as Robert and I pointed out because that should provide a defined behavior. If you're not, that might cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I'll try to explain in non-technical words. `What I understand regarding the Context is, I have to use it when multiple threads are using the GPU concurrently.` No, the context has a thread affinity: it "belongs" on a specific thread. If you're going to make calls on that context from another thread, you have to "move" the context over to that other thread. It doesn't matter because you're using the GPU *concurrently*, it matters because you're using the GPU *from different threads*.

Comment: Thank you Cicada, now I understand. No chance! It still crashes: I try cudaSetDevice(0); in each Thread BEFORE runCuda()... Using thread.join() then it works fine; .detach crashes. It seems I have to lose the Thread feature/functionality and serialize the tasks...

Comment: Oh, you say detach crashes? Then it probably means a thread is outliving one of the variables it is using. For example, a reference to a local variable created on the main thread (which exits *before* the detached threads, leading to a use-after-free bug).

Comment: @Cicada: This is for sure not the reason because the main thread never ends. It is a WebServer program which runs "forever". As answered below it is a class which makes the problem.